# Unable to stimulate change event in child component React redux jest

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to react redux and I am trying to unit test FormContainer component. But I am unable to simulate change event on Form component using enzyme or jest. In wrapper.instance() I am receiving null but I dont' think that should. If not then what is correct way of testing FormContainer.js file, because when I ran test coverage it showed me that change function was uncovered.

FormContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Form from "../components/Form";
import { isNumeric } from "../utils";

class FormContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      number: "",
      error: false
    };
  }
  // componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  //   console.log(nextProps, this.props, "main component");
  // }

  change = event => {
    let value = event.target.value;
    if (isNumeric(value) && value < 1001 && value >= 0) {
      if (value === "0") {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          error: true
        });
        return;
      } else {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          [event.target.name]: value,
          error: false
        });
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({ ...this.state, error: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form change={this.change} value={this.state} error={this.state.error} />
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { ...state };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FormContainer);
```

FormContainer.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import { shallow,mount } from 'enzyme';
import FormContainer from '../../containers/FormContainer';
import { findByAttr } from '../../utils';
import Form from '../../components/Form';

describe("Testing Form container", () => {
    let wrapper;
    let store;
    beforeEach(() => {
        const initialState = {}
        const mockStore = configureStore();
        store = mockStore(initialState);
        wrapper = shallow(<FormContainer store={store} />);
    });
    it("Should render without error ", () => {
        expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
    });

    it("Simulate change", () => {
        let component = wrapper.find(Form);
        const mockChange = jest.fn();
        wrapper.instance().change = mockChange;
    });
});
```

Testing Form container › Simulate change

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'change' of null

  22 |         let component = wrapper.find(Form);
  23 |         const mockChange = jest.fn();
> 24 |         wrapper.instance().change = mockChange;
     |         ^
  25 |     });
  26 | });

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/__test__/containers/FormContainer.test.js:24:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont need to import `import Form from '../../components/Form';` since we are only testing `FormContainer` component, so remove it.
and there is no event listener called `change`, Use `onChange` instead.

```
<Form onChange={this.change} value={this.state} error={this.state.error} />
```

Try changing this spec:

```
it("Simulate change", () => {
    let component = wrapper.find(Form);
    const mockChange = jest.fn();
    wrapper.instance().change = mockChange;
});
```

To:

```
it("Simulate change", () => {
    (wrapper.find(Form).first()).simulate('change');
    expect(wrapper.instance().change.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the thing is when is console.logged wrapper.debug() I got this :

`<ContextProvider value={{...}}>
  <FormContainer store={{...}} dispatch={[Function: dispatch]} />
</ContextProvider>`

When I tried console.log(wrapper.find(Form).debug()) I got `""`

So when I tried `(wrapper.find(Form).first()).simulate('change');` I got error `Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.`